# Disambiguation with QMetaObject::invokeMethod and multiple candidates

Tags: qt, qmetaobject

I wonder if it is possible to call a method with `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`, if the method has **optional parameters** like this.

```
class Foo {
    Q_INVOKABLE void myMethod(int a, bool b = true);
}
```

I have tried :

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(foo, "myMethod", Q_ARG(int, 42), Q_ARG(bool, true));
```

But the output tells me there are (of course) **multiple candidates**:

```
Candidates are:
    myMethod(int,bool)
    myMethod(int)
```

Is it possible to disambiguate `invokeMethod` so I am sure to call `myMethod(int,bool)` ?

EDIT: I found out that it was an issue with the namespaces for custom classes, instead of ìnt`and`bool`. I wrote a quick and dirty solution.

```
class Foo {
    Q_INVOKABLE void myMethod(bar::A a, blop::B b = blop::B::Default);
}

// When I need to call invokeMethod
auto success = QMetaObject::invokeMethod(foo, "myMethod", Q_ARG(A, A()),
                                             Q_ARG(B, B()));
if(!success) {
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(foo, "myMethod", Q_ARG(bar::A, bar::A()),
                                             Q_ARG(blop::B, blop::B()));
}
```

But this seems *very very very* dirty. Anyone got a good solution to handle this ussue?

Comment: Did you tried to pass arguments to method signature? `myMethod(bar::A, blop::B)` ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no "good solution" yet. Always fully qualify the arguments to the signals/slots and to the matching string-based `connect()` and `invokeMethod()`. The long story is that the lookup is done by string comparison, so you need a perfect match.